# Another String was not recognised as a valid DateTime And XML Element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datetime

I have an XML element which contains data in the following DATE format (the XML data is from a third party web service so i have no control over the data returned)

```
1/12/2012 and
2012
```

I am getting the error

*String was not recognised as a valid DateTime*

So i read around and tried (My C# isnt as efficient as VB .Net)

```
DateOfBirth = DateTime.TryParse(c.Element(ns + "date-span").Elements(ns + "begin").Any() ? c.Element(ns + "date-span").Element(ns + "begin").Value : DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

but whatever i try i either get a syntax error or string was not recognised.

The type of DateOfBirth in my SQL DB is Datetime - but changing this to NVARCHAR resolves the problem but this means i cant store it as a valid datetime format to perform datetime operations once the data is in the database.

Is there a way to overcome the above error or format 2012 to 01/01/2012? Or is the only way to do this is to store it as a NVARCHAR and then Convert.ToDateTime(*valueFromDatabase*) when i need to do operations on the date that has been saved?

Edit 1

```
GetCustomers = from c in XDoc.Descendants(ns + "customer")
                                  select
                                  new Customer
                                  {
                                      Name = c.Element(ns + "name").Value,
                                      DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(aa.Element(ns + "date-span").Elements(ns + "begin").Any() ? aa.Element(ns + "date-span").Element(ns + "begin").Value : DateTime.Now.ToString())
                                  };
```

Edit 2

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                        <metadata created=""2014-11-03T18:13:02.769Z"" xmlns=""http://example.com/ns/mmd-2.0#"" xmlns:ext=""http://example.com/ns/ext#-2.0"">
                            <customer-list count=""112"" offset=""0"">
                                <customer id=""5f6ab597-f57a-40da-be9e-adad48708203"" type=""Person"" ext:score=""100"">
                                    <name>Bobby Smith</name>
                                    <gender>male</gender>
                                    <country>US</country>
                                    <date-span>
                                        <begin>1965-02-18</begin>
                                        <end>false</end>
                                    </date-span> 
                                </customer> 
                                <customer id=""22"" type=""Person"" ext:score=""100"">
                                    <name>Tina Smith</name>
                                    <gender>Female</gender>
                                    <country>US</country>
                                    <date-span>
                                        <end>false</end>
                                    </date-span> 
                                </customer>
                                <customer id=""30"" type=""Person"" ext:score=""500"">
                                    <name>George</name>
                                    <gender>Male</gender>
                                    <country>US</country>
                                    <date-span>
                                        <begin>1965</begin>
                                        <end>false</end>
                                    </date-span> 
                                </customer> 
                            </customer-list>    
                         </metadata>";
```

Comment: What's the value of `c.Element(ns + "date-span").Element(ns + "begin").Value`? Is it `1/12/2012`?

Comment: Yes - however another record may have it as just 2012 (no day/month) from the XML returned

Comment: Does `1/12/2012` mean December 1, 2012 or January 12, 2012?

Comment: It means 1 December 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Well*, looks like [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes `string[]` as a format can be a solution;

```
string s = "";
string[] format = new [] {"yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy"};
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Successfull parsing for 2012 and 1/12/2012
}
```

I assume your first digit is for days. If it is not, you can add `MM/d/yyyy` format in your string array. And if your days and month parts have leading zeros for single digits (like `01/01/2012`), you also need `dd/MM/yyyy` format as well.

Comment: My code is part of a Linq query so how would i amend the code i posted? If this doesnt make sense i can post a snippet

Comment: @Computer I'm not good at LINQ but posting your code snippet can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format is what you listed, then you could use TryParseExact overload that allows multiple formats.

```
var year = "2012";
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(year,new []{"yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}, null,DateTimeStyles.None,out result);
```

Regarding the LINQ you posted: .Any() means 1 or more, it looks like you want exactly one or none...so possibly use .SingleOrDefault() instead of .Any()

Further, in both of your conditional statements you are just returning today's date:

`var birthDate = condition : executes when condition true ? executes when condition is false;`

So, defensive coding aside, you want the try parse exact to run like:

```
DateTime birthDate;
var dateToParse =  c.Element(ns + "date-span").Element(ns + "begin").Value;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToParse,new []{"yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}, null,DateTimeStyles.None,out result);
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but again im not sure if i can use Linq the way i am. Code is under Edit 1

Comment: @Computer will you post a snippet of the xml?  Are you using LINQtoXML?

Comment: Ive added the XML im using under Edit 2. Yes LinqToXML